# Using Code Snippets in Class Extensions - shortcut won't work

Tags: xcode, code-snippets

I've got a code snippet I made and works perfectly when adding properties to my .h file. 
[image]

But I don't want many of my properties in my .h because they should be internal only. So I head into the .m and make a Class Extension. Here, my code snippets won't work with my shortcut I'm not sure why. Ok, "scope" seems like the issue, but it's set to "All" (see pic above).

Here's an example

**.m**

```
@interface Foo()
// if I type in 'pps' I won't get snippet completion
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *bar;
@end

@implementation Foo
```

So how to I get these things to work here? I'm getting really tired of mistyping this line over and over again. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't tell you why, but it works (only) if you set the "Language" of the Code Snippet to "Objective-C" instead of "Objective-C++".

Comment: I didn't even notice I had put in `Objective-C++` instead of `Objective-C`. I'm completely happy with it being the later since it doesn't impact anything (here)